# Changing date format before binding JSON data to a jquery template

Tags: jquery, json, templates

I am binding a JSON object to a query template and I need to change how the date is being displayed.

In the JSON - I have the following key/value "dateOfTheMonth": "10-11-2015” and I need to do two things.

1. Display the date in the template like this “1st”, “2nd”, “3rd" - so just the day and appending the correct ordinal indicator (“st, nd, rd, th”)
2. Also keep the original format for use in a data attribute

Here the JSON...

```
"data": {
    "currentMonth": "November",
    "calendar": [
        {
            "dateOfTheMonth": "1-11-2015",
            "isDateUnavailable": true,
            "isDateSoldOut": false,
        },
        {
            "dateOfTheMonth": “2-11-2015",
            "isDateUnavailable": true,
            "isDateSoldOut": false,

        }
    ]

}
```

The function I use to get the JSON  data (from an API) and bind it to a template

```
}
getDays(function (data) {
$("#template").tmpl(data.data.calendar).appendTo("#week");
});
```

And this is the template:

```
<script id="template" type="text/html">
<div class="day-container" data-arrival-Date=“${dateOfTheMonth}">
    ${dateWithOrdinal} // so here would display 1st, 2nd etc
    </div>
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
   var indate="1-11-2015";//your date here
   var parts = indate.split('-');

  function ordinal_suffix_of(i) {
    var j = i % 10,
      k = i % 100;
    if (j == 1 && k != 11) {
      return i + "st";
    }
    if (j == 2 && k != 12) {
      return i + "nd";
    }
    if (j == 3 && k != 13) {
      return i + "rd";
    }
    return i + "th";
  }

  
  var opdate =  ordinal_suffix_of(parts[0]) + "-" +parts[1] + "-" +parts[2];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =opdate;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but whow would I filter the json with this? Where should I put it?

Comment: Many thanks again! I still don't know how I would add this into the template. Maybe an .each over the json data and run it through your suffix funtion

Comment: yaa you need pass dateOfTheMonth  through this function..getDays(function (data) { "you can call this function here"}

Comment: Thats great - it worked. I added it to the template like this - ${ordinal_suffix_of(dateOfTheMonth)} - in case anyone needs to know